# How to get time and date from datetime stamp in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have one string like `8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM`. I want to save in variable like `$dat = '8/29/2011'` and `$tme = '11:16:12 AM'`

How to achieve that? Can you give me example?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

E.g.

```
<?php
$s = '8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM';
$dt = new DateTime($s);

$date = $dt->format('m/d/Y');
$time = $dt->format('H:i:s');

echo $date, ' | ', $time;
```

see http://docs.php.net/class.datetime

---

edit: To keep the AM/PM format use

```
$time = $dt->format('h:i:s A');
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the strtotime function, as long as the dates are after 1/1/1970 -

```
<?php

$s = strtotime('8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM');

$date = date('m/d/Y', $s);
$time = date('H:i:s A', $s);

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

strtotime creates a UNIX timestamp from the string you pass to it.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
    $date = strtotime('8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM');
    $dat = date('m/d/y', $date);
    $tme = date('H:m:s A',$date);

?>
```

For more information about date() function, plz visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not the cleanest way of doing it, but you can use an explode (note that there is NO validation at all here). It will be faster than a proper date manipulation.

```
$str = '8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM';
$dates = explode(' ', $str);
$dat = $dates[0];
$time = $dates[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

If your version of PHP is new enough, check out date_parse() and the array it returns. You can then format date or time portions using the relevant entries.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$mystring_datetime = ....;
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s A', $mystring_datetime );
$d = $dt->format('m/d/Y');
$t = $dt->format('H:i:s A');
```

You could also do something like this but it's not preferred way:

```
$mystring_datetime = ....;
list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $mystring_datetime, 2);
```

Now, `$date` and `$time` have appropriate values...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, and the perfect example can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Good luck,